# ios-sending notification with firebase

Tags: php, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create app with notification. Notification must be sended from php file to firebase and then to device. At first i have tried to send with firebase console and it works perfect. But when i try to send notificaion using php then i have problems. It says successfully sended but i didn't get any notifications. there is my php for sending notification:

```
<?php 
function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'to' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = my api key',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

$data = array("alert" => "How it is going today");
$token = "fJVM7YrWGQg......";


$message = array("message" => " FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION TEST MESSAGE");
$message_status = send_notification($token, $message);
echo $message_status;
```

?>

I have searched for fix it. But nothing helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hej everybody, i found solution. if someone search hope it will help:

```
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR_FIREBASE_API_KEY' );
$registrationIds = array( "devices firebasetoken here." );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array(
        'body'  => "message text",
        'title'     => "message title",
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => 1,
    );
$fields = array(
            'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
            'notification'      => $msg
        );

$headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

Comment: Hi @MRustamzade   can You tell me please that how you handle it inside App . Thanks please let me know.

Comment: @AvinashMishra i did it as well as here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: @MRustamzade how can i send some extra keys with the push? like order_id or type?