# Get result then call other function in background

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the best practice to do something in background? I have 2 function for example. first one called `addDataToDatabase` adds data to `database` (after adding data to database i should return success) another function called `sendNotificationToUser` sends notification to user using firebase. But if i call first function and then second it takes too long time. Because `firebase` takes too long time. I thought it will be better if first adds data to database and returns success message and then it will send notification automatically in background. Is it possible  and is it good practice to do something like this? Problem is i am using shared hosting

Comment: Do you have an example of some code we can see to see what order the events are being processed in? Maybe it's just the structure you are calling them in..

Comment: @Kaboom in adding to database i have tested and it is very fast. but when i send notification using firebase http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427682/4459647 it takes too long.